# How to copy a derived model instance in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, copy

What is the right way to make a copy of a derived model (full copy including the base model)?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    f = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Derived(Item):
    pass
```

The following does not work:

```
derived = Derived.objects.create()
derived.pk = None
derived.save()
```

Related bug report: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29871

Comment: But hasn't Tim given you the answer on that bug? Do `derived. item_ptr = None`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It is not reliable, as his code depends and does different things on whether we work with `Derived` object or with its base class. This is very error-prone and users of my library would do this error certainly